# Thermodynamics - Number Of Component

Tags: thermodynamics, phase

> $\ce{CaCO3(s) -> CaO(s) + CO2(aq)}$

It is said that the number of constituents for this reaction is three . 
I think number of constituents refer to the number of different elements in the system . As there are 3 different species so it is three.
But for the number of components it is said that as $\ce{CaCO3 and CaO are both in solid state they form only one component}$ and the other component is $\ce{CO2 which is in aqueous form}$
So there are 2 components . 
I couldn't completely understand what is number of component ?
And is the above definition of number of constituents is correct ?

Comment: Is seems like there is some mixed up terminology here, particularly in the second part of you question:"$\ce{CaCO3}$ and $\ce{CaO}$ are both in solid state they form only one component...".  Is this possibly a translation of some text where "component" should really be "phase"?  Regarding the first part of your question, I would think the constituents of the reaction are $\ce{CaCO3}$, $\ce{CaO}$ and $\ce{CO2}$.